# Jmeter Graphql Variable Int cannot represent non-integer value

Tags: jmeter, graphql

Im doing a simple coverage of a mutation that has a variable an initial value that is returned in the login.

I defined my extractor and store the value in `storedInitialValue` but whenever I want to use it in the GraphQL Variables it throw type error

I added my GraphQl Http Request with the query

```
mutation getSequenceFromInitialValue ($initialValue: Int!) { 
    getSequenceFromInitialValue (initialValue: $initialValue) {
       sequence
    }
}
```

And then in the variables

```
{ 
"initialValue": "${storedInitialValue}"
}
```

I checked the value of `storedInitialValue` and it has the expected value but it throw the error `Int cannot represent non-integer value`

And If I define the variables like

```
{ 
"initialValue": ${storedInitialValue} 
}
```

The query fail because `"Variable \"$initialValue\" of required type \"Int!\" was not provided`

I trie with a JSR223 preprocessor and run into the same error, is there a way to handle the GraphQl query type in Jmeter?

I install Jmeter without plugin with `brew install jmeter`

Comment: I am having the same issue. Did you figure it out? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to remove quotation marks from the variable definition:

i.e. change this:

```
{ 
"initialValue": "${storedInitialValue}"
}
```

to this:

```
{ 
"initialValue": ${storedInitialValue}
}
```

More information:

- [JSON Data Types](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_datatypes.asp)
- [Introducing JMeter 5.4: New Features and Abilities](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-jmeter5-4-new-features-and-abilities)
- [Performance Testing a GraphQL Server with Apache JMeter (Tutorial for Beginners)](https://medium.com/swlh/performance-testing-a-graphql-server-with-apache-jmeter-tutorial-for-beginners-da5f7cf8b810)

Comment: If I do that I get the second error I put in the description
`The query fail because "Variable \"$initialValue\" of required type \"Int!\" was not provided`